# How to make an Ionic-like CLI in Python

Tags: python, command-line-interface

I want to know how to make a CLI such that you can make choices with up arrow and down arrow and the selected option is highlighted as well, like when you run `ionic start new_project`:

[image: Ionic CLI interface]

Comment: not sure if it helps, but https://docs.python.org/3/library/readline.html. `import readline; input()` (or `raw_input()` in python 2)

Comment: @Paolo I know about these modules but I don't think this module provides the CLI style i am after. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you would like something more like a TUI (Text User Interface), I recommend prompt-toolkit: https://github.com/prompt-toolkit/python-prompt-toolkit or npyscreen: https://github.com/npcole/npyscreen